# Duplicate files in pom.xml

Tags: android-studio

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK pom.xml
    File1: /Users/michaelnares/Documents/TripMatcher2/app/libs/library_sliding.jar
    File2: /Users/michaelnares/Documents/TripMatcher2/app/libs/roundedimageview.jar
```

Is there any way of viewing the pom.xml within Android Studio?  I can only see build.gradle.  My top-level build.gradle is as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

My app-level build.gradle is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tripmatcher"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'

    // glide is added to load the g+ profile image. Ignore if you want
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/facebook_sdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}
```

As far as I can see, everything should work fine.

Comment: There is no pom.xml, all you can see is the build.gradle

Comment: OK, is there another way to solve this issue please?

Comment: Did anyone figure out how to solve the issue?

Comment: See my own answer, I seem to remember manually deleting the pom.xml from the Eclipse project did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

We do not have a `pom.xml` in android projects using `Android Studio`, All dependencies of your project are in `build.gradle` file. The issue below is because you need to specify which libraries of google service you want to use. Like :

```
   compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1"
```

Comment: See updated question.  I have included these in my app-level build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else coming across this problem, manually deleting the pom.xml file from the Eclipse project and then creating the .jar after that did the trick for me.